# winrar alternative

Tags: archive, rar

Is there a strong archive application like winrar with GUI and can unrar 5.1 versions of rar files?

Also important is the ability to compress files to rar with password and the feature to split the file to parts with specific sizes and add comments to them.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't File Roller do all that (possibly requires additional plugins)? It is installed by default I believe, or else it can be easily installed through the software center (or other package management)

Info on File Roller:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Roller
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller